# Retrieve loaded javascript libraries

Tags: javascript, http, web

When a web page loads, it might load external javascript libraries.
How can I retrieve all those libraries? (Assuming using a tool, script).

Comment: goto developer console and click on sources tab you can find all scripts and css files of a web page

Comment: what u mean by retrieve?

Comment: I mean by dumping all the javascript that a web page loads.

Comment: It's not that straightforward, the Javascript can inject more script tags to load yet more Javascript. Ideally you'd want to really capture the HTTP requests and look for `text/javascript` content etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get list of loaded JavaScript libraries, in sources tab of development console of chrome.

There is another way to find is using chrome plugins, There are number of plugins available, but I like [Appspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/appspector/homgcnaoacgigpkkljjjekpignblkeae)

Comment: Please update your plugin link, he give 404